# How to change a UID of a Virtual Box VDI

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I downloaded XP+IE6 VM from modern.ie.
I created a VM and configured it.
I have copied my VMDK to another location, changed its name and want to create another VM from that to install IE7.
I get the message "Cannot register the hard disk...because a hard disk with UID '...' already exists.

Does anyone know how to get pass this?

Thanks

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/468187/trying-to-open-a-vm-config-which-has-the-same-uuid-as-an-existing-virtual-machin/468188

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VBoxManage` from the command line like so:

`VBoxManage clonehd C:\Path\To\Disk.vdi C:\Path\To\New\Disk.vdi`

**Documentation**

- VBoxManage: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi
- Disk Images: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#vdis

Comment: i've tried it and i get the same error message in the command line